# System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded in developer console

Tags: apex, developer-console

I am having 3.5k records but while executing the code i get

**System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded**

Although i need to update only 360 records whose duplicate__c is true.

```
List<Account> act = new List<Account>();
for(Account accou: [select name,duplicate__c from account where duplicate__c=true])
{
    accou.duplicate__c=false;
    act.add(accou);
        update act;

}
```

Comment: You are executing inside a for look, each DML may cause additional triggers, why not use dataloader for this operation?

Comment: 360 record updates per transaction could fail with CPU exception if you have downstream triggers, wfr, process builders, flows -- you can gain some insight into where the CPU time goes by using the Developer Console profiling feature or just looking at the debug log. If this is a 1 time anon apex script, run it multiple times with a Limit x as part of the SOQL

Answer (score 1):

You need to update records in bulk.

You cannot perform more than 150 DML operations in a single transaction. as you have written update stmt in a for loop, you ran into an issue. Just move it outside of for loop.

```
List<Account> act = new List<Account>();
for(Account accou: [select Id,name,duplicate__c from account where duplicate__c=true])
{
    accou.duplicate__c=false;
    act.add(accou);
}
update act;
```

Again you can update max 10000 records in a single transaction. In your case, there are 3.5k records only, so it should work.

Also, [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code) will be a very helpful article to know how to bulkify your code.

[Apex Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm)

Comment: i try your approach and move soql outside for loop still the error remain same.   List<Account> act = new List<Account>([select name,duplicate__c from account where duplicate__c=true]);
for(Account accou: act)
{.......

Comment: can you paste error in question?

Comment: Line: 95, Column: 1
System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Comment: You do not need the Id in you query as it is automatically returned. The only time you need Id is if you are editing from the query table within the dev console tool palette

Answer (score 0):

Since i cannot update all query at  once so i need to  use limit

```
List<Account> accouUpd= new List<Account>();
List<Account> act = new List<Account>([select name,duplicate__c from account where duplicate__c=true limit 80] );
for(Account accou: act)
{
    accou.duplicate__c=false;
    accouUpd.add(accou);
        update accouUpd;

}
```